# Woocommerce variation selection doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, I have the variation section where costumer can select a variation for a product. Although, that variation dropdown menu doesn't work, the sku doesnt change and when adding to cart doesnt show the variation.

The variation code is in variable.php as supposed. I already tried modifying it but the problem presists.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'
      data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>"
      data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php esc_html_e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'exzo' ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) :
            $color = false;


            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) );

            ?>

            <?php
            $arr_color = null;
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $term_id = $term->term_id;

                $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term_id, '', 'phoen_color', true );

                if ( isset( $thumbnail_id[sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) . '_thumbnail_id_phoen_color'][0] ) ) {
                    if ( isset( $thumbnail_id[sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) . '_thumbnail_id_phoen_color'][0]{1} ) ) {
                        $color = true;
                    }
                    $arr_color[] = array(
                        'slug' => $term->slug,
                        'color_hex' => $thumbnail_id[sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) . '_thumbnail_id_phoen_color'][0]
                    )
                    ?>

                    <?php
                }
            }


            ?>
<?php if ( $color != true ) : ?>
                    <div class="row col-xs-b40">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div
                                    class="h6 detail-data-title size-1"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ) . ':'; ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <?php
                            ob_start();
                            $selected = isset( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name )] ) ? wc_clean( urldecode( $_REQUEST['attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute_name )] ) ) : $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $attribute_name );
                            wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array(
                                'options' => $options,
                                'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                'product' => $product,
                                'selected' => $selected,
                                'class' => 'SlectBox'
                            ) );
                            ?>
                            <?php

                            echo  str_replace( '"" ',  ' " ',  ob_get_clean() );
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Already tried modifying to the last part into this:

```
  <?php  $output = '<div class="product-variations-dropdown">
    <select id="available-variations" class="" name="available_variations">';

$output .= '<option value="">'. __('Choose a variation') .'</option>';

foreach( $available_variations as $variation ){
    $option_value = array();

    foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $attribute => $term_slug ){
        $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $attribute );
        $attribute_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name; // Attribute name
        $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name; // Attribute value term name

        $option_value[] = $attribute_name . ': '.$term_name;
    }
    $option_value = implode( ' | ', $option_value );

    $output .= '<option value="'.$variation['variation_id'].'">'.$option_value.'</option>';

}
$output .= '
    </select>
</div>';

echo $output;?>
```

So basically it was supposed to update the variation_id value when a different variation was chosen, although it doesn't do anything. There is any way to change the dropdown selection to update the variation_id value?

Link: https://biokimica.eu/produto/bio-k1-lava-tudo/

Comment: you don't need to modify it in order to work it  should work by default, and if there no major changes you are doing in the variable template then do not edit it, however in order to troubleshoot the issue just rename this template so woocommerce can use the default one and check if its working or not  because as i can see there is several changes are made to this template

Comment: I agree with @kashalo, Woocommerce default templates can perfectly handle product variation selection, price update on change, correct add to cart etc... You should try to put back default templates and see if it works. If so, you'll know that your updates are causing the issue.